# Encrypting .rtf and .docx files programmatically using java

Tags: java, public-key-encryption, documents

I am able to encrypt and decrypt .txt files using RSA algorithm in java.
How can I do same for .rtf and .docx files?

**Update: other files are encrypting but generating zero byte size file !!**

here is the code

```
public void encrypt(String inputFile, String outputFile, PublicKey publicKey) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA);
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    privKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    pubKey = keyPair.getPublic();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    byte[] block = new byte[1024];
    int i;
    try {
        while ((i = fis.read(block)) != -1) {
            cos.write(block, 0, i);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    } finally {
        cos.close();
    }
}
```

Even if I copy simple xml content in a text file and encrypt it, I get zero byte encrypted file :(

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: You haven't even told us how you're doing it for text files, so how can we give you concrete information on how to do it for other files? But since encryption algorithms usually just work on bytes, it shouldn't matter whether those bytes represent a .txt file, an .rtf, a .docx or even a .jpg. If you want a more specific answer, you'll probably have to give a more specific question.

Comment: I don't have access to code right now. I followed example on Oracle's site. Code is working for both text and rtf but I get zero byte size file for rtf and no error.

Comment: Basically I am generating public private key and saving them in file. Then encrypting txt, rtf files using public key. Then decrypting the encrypted file using same public key.

Comment: can some one answer to my issue?
why this is still closed!!

Comment: I cannot imagine a reason why above code could work for a type of file and not for another one. Are you sure you have no mistake in the file name ? Windows system are known to hide known file extensions but when opening a file programmatically you must give its full name.